# How to generate a List of Dates with Start/End sorted by Month in Drupal7/Views?

Tags: sorting, drupal-7, view, datefield

I have installed Drupal7 and created a content type (why not call it 'event' for now) to which I added a date field (lets name it 'event-date'). Some event-dates have start- and end-dates.
Now I want to generate a list of these events using 'views', sorted by Month, where every event is listed in one line, even the events with start- and end-dates should have one line for every day the event lasts - not only the start-till-end-row listing.

for example instead of

> JANUARY
> Mo, 04/02/2013 - 20:00 to Th, 06/02/2013 - 20:00  Event1

I need

> JANUARY
> Mo, 04/02/2013 Event1
>
> Tu, 05/02/2013 Event1
>
> Th, 06/02/2013 Event1

How could I realize that? thnx!

Answer (score 0):

First create your own time formate with 'admin/config/regional/date-time'. Then in views create an extra output field of the date you want to group to months. Then group the output in your list or table within views and you are done.